# populate a form from json (dojo)

Tags: json, dojo

I have a json `{"Name":"@@","Phone":"9999999999","EMail":"example@ex.com"}`
i want to fill the values from this object to a form...how to do that?
here is the form

```
<form data-dojo-type="dojox.form.Manager" name="form" id="form" method="post">
<tr><td>
<input type="text" required="true" name="Name" id="Name" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"/></tr></td>
<tr><td>
<input type="text" name="Phone" id="Phone" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"/></tr></td>
<tr><td>
<input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"/></tr></td>
</form>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

To set value in form try this:-

```
var obj = {"Name":"@@","Phone":"9999999999","EMail":"example@ex.com"};
dijit.byId('form').set('value',obj);
```

I know its late but its working:-

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a simple javascript loop over the json.

```
var data = JSON.parse(jsonDataString);
for (index in data) {
    var el = document.getElementById(index);
    if (el)
        el.value = data[el];
}
```

Comment: This will work in some scenarios, but it sets the value directly on the DOM nodes, bypassing any value logic in the Dojo widgets.  So you will likely bypass validation warnings, and all the other stuff in the widgets.

Answer (score 0):

`dojox.form.Manager` includes `dijit.form._FormMixin` which provides a .setValues function.
You should be able to call `form.setValues` with your JSON object. The advantage of this is that it'll correctly call `.set("value", ...)` on each of the widgets properly to ensure that the Dijit widgets have the new values.  Simply assigning the '`.value`' property on the DOM node may well bypass the Dijit logic.

There's an equivalent `.getValues` on `_FormMixin` too, which does the reverse.